# jQuery UI issues with tables in dialogs

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog

I have a jQuery UI dialog to which I applied a padding, and inside the dialog I have a long table. I then configure the dialog to be of limited height in order to have a scrollbar.

It seems that whenever a nowrap is applied to the table cells, the padding to the right of the table is covered by the scrollbar. If I remove the nowrap, it works fine.

Here is an editable example:

http://jsbin.com/okolap/4/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it only happens when you set the dialog's width to `auto`.

One workaround is to set the table's width to 100% and reset the dialog's width to a fixed length. The length needs to add a padding equal or larger than the width of the scroll bar. For example:

```
var newWidth = $('.Dialog').width() + 50;
$('.Dialog').width(newWidth);
```

See this in action: http://jsbin.com/okolap/10/.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out too. I found a jQuery plugin to detect the scrollbar size called "getscrollbarwidth", from Brandon Aaron. It works but then I was told by some jQuery developer that width: "auto" is not a valid option. Maybe that's the reason for the problem, not sure though. I'll have to go with the workaround as I can't predict the table width so I need to make this auto.