# jquery-ui dialog table does not appear, but ul does

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I have a simple web page where for each row of data, I can pop up a jQuery UI dialog with the details of that row. Since there can be multiple rows in the sub-query a table is the best choice.

The jQuery for this is pretty simple:

```
$('#dialog').dialog(
    {   
        autoOpen: false, 
        title: "Backup Job Detail",
        width: 400,
        height: 450
        }
);

$('.row').click( function(){
    $('#dialog').dialog("open");
});
```

The (resulting) HTML looks like the following: (updated with the row contents)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>NAS Execution Groovy Servlet</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/executions.js'></script>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css'></link>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/jquery-ui.css'></link>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/nas.css'></link>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='results' class='execution-results'>
        <p id='rpt-header'>
           <span class='rpt-header-txt'>Backup Schedule Report for </span>
           <span class='rpt-header-asset'>MyAsset</span>
        </p>
        <table id='nas-table'>
            <thead>
              <tr class='table-header'>
                    <th>Schedule Name</th>
                    <th>Backup Product</th>
                    <th>Size Mb</th>
                    <th>Start Time</th>
                    <th>Duration</th>
                    <th>Expiration Date</th>
                    <th>Wed 14</th>
             </tr>

            </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class='row'>
              <td class='row-data'>schedule_name</td>
              <td class='row-data'>backupProduct</td>
              <td id='size-mb' class='row-data'>sizeStr</td>
              <td class='row-data'>start_time</td>
              <td class='row-data'>duration secs</td>
              <td class='row-data'>expiration_date</td>
              <td class='row-center'>
                <a class='tooltip' href='#'>
                  <img id='success-fail' src='img/partial.gif'></img>
                  <span class='classic'>Message returned is : message_text</span>
                </a>
             </td>
        </tr>
              <div id='dialog'>
                <table class='inner-table'>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>JOB_TYPE_NAME</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Incr Backup</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

The dialog never appears, the the table shows up at the end. I shortened the size of the table meant to go in the dialog just in case size were an issue, as the link posted by one commenter might imply.

If I replace the table with a list (ul), it behaves perfectly.

Any ideas what is the deal?

Brian

Comment: It would help to see the markup of your table+row that gets clicked. It would also help to see the code that is generating the table content for the dialog. How are you adding that resultant markup to the dialog?

Comment: maybe this would help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615261/jquery-ui-issues-with-tables-in-dialogs

Comment: Does the `inner-table` class in your CSS contain `display: none;`?

Comment: The inner-table class has no CSS markup. I'll post the entire HTML if it makes it easier.

Comment: jimp - the table content in my real code is done in Groovy, but I recreated this example in pure HTML to see if the inner code were an issue.

Comment: Any other thoughts? None of these suggestions have solved this perplexing issue.

Comment: Can you make an example on jsfiddle or jsbin?

Comment: This code works for me.  Make sure your jQuery is in the $(document).ready (function() {..});

Answer (score 0):

Move your dialog DIV under your "results" DIV.  You can't put your dialog DIV in the middle of your table like you have it.

```
<div id='results' class='execution-results'>
...
</div>

<div id='dialog'>
  <table class='inner-table'>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>JOB_TYPE_NAME</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Incr Backup</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```